# cual es la diferencia entre progamar js y programar js en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

cual es la diferencia entre programar JavaScript y programar JavaScript en node.js en poca palabras puedo reciclar un codido de js. formulado en node.js para mi uso
tengo una problema pero no se si es de sintaxis soy nuevo programando aprendo por mi propia cuenta con video en youtube.! :D :D espero aprender a programar espero que no me rechacen por no ser un experto o no tener conocimientos básico como digo aprendo por mi cuenta y no tengo bases muy fortalecida por ahora y cualquier apoyo se lo agradeceré

Comment: JS es un lenguaje de programación y NodeJS es un framework de este, es decir, que añade más funcionalidades al lenguaje.

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Comment: @anythingg nodejs NO es un framework sino *un entorno de ejecución para JavaScript construido con el motor de JavaScript V8 de Chrome.* https://nodejs.org/es/, nodejs permite trabajar con js del lado del servidor

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript es una implementación de ECMAScript, un estándar que define el lenguaje de programación.

Los navegadores web tienen un intérprete incorporado para JavaScript, junto con un montón de bibliotecas y un entorno de ejecución para trabajar con páginas web.

Node.js es un intérprete y un entorno de ejecución para JavaScript que incluye un montón de librerías para usar JavaScript como lenguaje de programación de propósito general, con un énfasis en la asincronía y las operaciones sin bloqueo. Node en realidad ejecuta el mismo intérprete que Google Chrome (motor de JavaScript V8), pero proporciona un conjunto diferente de bibliotecas y un entorno de ejecución diferente. También incluye un sistema de gestión de paquetes (NPM) y algunas extensiones de lenguaje que generalmente no se encuentran en los navegadores (por ejemplo, los módulos).

El intérprete JS en Google Chrome y el intérprete JS en Node.js son esencialmente lo mismo. La diferencia es que en un navegador tu objetivo final es modificar cosas en una página web (texto, gráficos, hojas de estilo, etc.). En Node.js es para ejecutar código de propósito general que puede hacer cualquier cosa, desde ejecutar un servidor web hasta manipular archivos, y Node.js también puede ejecutar bloques de código JS desde la línea de comandos.

<sub>Fuente: revisado de [What is the difference between JavaScript and Node.js?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JavaScript-and-Node-js)</sub>

Comment: amigo es decir que si quiero usar el script codificado en node.js debo hacerle un cambio para que funcione con motor chrome, estoy interesado en hacer una script js pero estilo extension

Comment: [Is it possible to develop Google Chrome extensions using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12575965/)

Answer (score -2):

Entre Javascript y Node. js no hay ninguna diferencia, ya que el uno forma parte del otro, Node. js es un complemento para usar javascript del lado del servidor.

Comment: Si que hay diferencias, ademas porfavor revisa [answer], de hecho se supone que ninguno de los dos deberíais haber respondido a esta pregunta, puesto que las preguntas basadas en opiniones **NO** son validas aquí en stackoverflow, y según el manual del sitio este tipo de preguntas **NO** deben responderse, stackoverflow no es wikipedia, si alguien requiere opiniones debera ir a yahoo, consultarlo en google o sitios de ese estilo etc, en cambio stackoverflow resuelve dudas mas concretas sobre un codigo en especifico.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración se que no son Wikipedia ni yahoo, mi intensión no es hacer sentir ofendido a nadie, solo quise una opinión soy nuevo programando y aprendiendo por mi cuenta y entender lo que dice wikipedia es difícil y quise preguntar de malo de las personas profesionales como uds, la verdad quiero aprender este arte de programar y espero me tengan paciencia y espero también aportar porque no